# Retrieve data from every subnode of firebase database and display in recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have a root node "products" which stores various sub nodes such as sub_product1, sub_product2 etc. Each sub_product node contains two or more objects ( of same class "Product"). I want to retrieve only 1 object from every sub_product node and display it in recyclerview.
Following is the demo structure of the database :

[image: demo database structure]

I don't think that this feature is available in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase adapters in FirebaseUI show the child nodes of the location or the query that you bind them to. There is no feature to show lower-level descendants. If you need this functionality, you will have to build it yourself - possibly using the code of the adapters in FirebaseUI for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRfkm.png)

I had my firebase databse as:

Category

```
 1

   name:"xyz"

   Image:"hzbabjaa"

  2

   name:"xyz"

   Image:"hzbabjaa"

  3

   name:"xyz"

   Image:"hzbabjaa"

   4

   name:"xyz"

   Image:"hzbabjaa"
```

Here in this firebase database i retrieve the data of object with the key name.
you can give the some key to the data whose you want to retrieve in the firebaseAdapter. Then make a java class where you get the name as i used:

public class Category {

```
private String Name;
private String Image;

public Category() {
}

public Category(String name, String image) {
    Name = name;
    Image = image;
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}

public String getImage() {
    return Image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    Image = image;
}
```

}

And then finally i included it as shown:

protected void onBindViewHolder(final MenuViewHolder holder, int position, Category model) {
                        holder.tvMenuName.setText(model.getName());

}

Comment: in your case 01, 02 ,03 etc are the objects that you're retrieving. In my case, sub_product1, sub_product2 etc are references that contain objects that I want to retrieve.

Comment: what is further inside sub_product1,sub_product2,sub_product3, etc

Comment: they contain a list of objects which belong to custom class "Product"